# Как можно получить данные о разрешении экрана устройства при помощи Python или его модулей?

Tags: python, kivy

Как можно получить данные о разрешении экрана устройства при помощи Python или его модулей?

Comment: Посмотрите < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857346/can-you-obtain-physical-size-of-device-in-kivy>

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.size посмотрите